# grep from a log file to get count

Tags: shell, scripting, awk, grep, sh

I have to get certain count from files. The grep statement i am using is like this :

```
counter_pstn=0
completed_count_pstn=0
rec=0
for rec in `(grep "merged" update_completed*.log | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/ //g' | cut -d':' -f2)`
do
if [ $counter_pstn -eq 0 ]
then
completed_count_pstn=$rec
else
completed_count_pstn=$(($completed_count_pstn+$rec))
fi
counter_pstn=$(($counter_pstn+1))
done
echo "Completed Orders PSTN Primary " $completed_count_pstn
```

But the log file contains data in this format :

```
2500 rows merged.
2500 rows merged.
2500 rows merged.
2500 rows merged.2500 rows merged.
2500 rows merged.
2500 rows merged.
```

As a result , it is missing out the count of one merge(eg on line 4 of output).How do i modify the grep or use another function to get the count. NOTE that the 2500 number maybe for different logs. So we have to use "rows merged" pattern to get the count. i have tried -o ,-w grep options,but it is not working.

Expected output from above data:

```
17500
```

Actual output showing :

```
15000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
perl -p -lne 's/merged./merged.\n/g' your_file|awk '{a+=$1}END{print a}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use awk with '.' as the record separator since that seems to be what you want to indicat the end of each record:

```
$ cat file
2500 rows merged.
2500 rows merged.2500 rows merged.
2500 rows merged.

$ awk -v RS='.' '/merged/{sum+=$1} END{print "sum=" sum}' file
sum=10000
```

Answer (score 0):

what is your grep -V output?

anyway, you can do it without grep:

```
sed 's/merged\./\n/g' file|awk '{x+=$1}END{print x}'
```

test

```
kent$  echo "2500 rows merged.
2500 rows merged.
2500 rows merged.
2500 rows merged.2500 rows merged.
2500 rows merged.
2500 rows merged."|sed 's/merged\./\n/g'|awk '{x+=$1}END{print x}'                                                                                                         
17500
```

Comment: is it showing 17500 as output on your comp...becoz it is printing 15000 in mine :(....i dont understand how that can happen...anyways grep -v is a long log script except for the merge part.do you want me to put it here?